# Share post as post (not quote) on facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-share, socialshare

I am currently working with Ruby On Rails gem [social_share_buttons](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button) and whenever I share a post with shareable links, the post comes as `USER shared a quote`, not `USER shared a post`. It is requirement to not to share the post as a quote. If you type text before sharing, the quote becomes a post. I will be very happy if there is a bypass for this if this is a limitation from Facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their source code, [you can see they are passing the data to the facebook/sharer.php url with the "quote" param](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/social-share-button.coffee#L42) renders the post as a quote. But after some testing and researching, it seems that any description or quote param is treated as a quote by the user. This plugin doesn't support non-quote text in a post by default.

Facebook (among others) has an extremely tight API now. It's hard to get a hobby application approved. However, if this feature is important, you'd need to use the Dialog API and get your app approved to get your app_id before you can begin implementing this solution.